# Magento 2: what is the $data array constructor parameter?

Tags: magento2, php, dependency-injection, di, preference

So I noticed that in most models and blocks, there's **this `array $data = []` given as the last parameter of the constructor**.

For example `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct`

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
    \Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper $postDataHelper,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Resolver $layerResolver,
    CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
    \Magento\Framework\Url\Helper\Data $urlHelper,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->_catalogLayer = $layerResolver->get();
    $this->_postDataHelper = $postDataHelper;
    $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository;
    $this->urlHelper = $urlHelper;
    parent::__construct(
        $context,
        $data
    );
}
```

I also know that, when dealing with preferences, you **still have to keep that parameter in the end of your constructor parameters list** when you add more parameters than the original constructor.

So I've got **several questions regarding this array**:

- what is it ?
- how to use it ?
- why do we need to keep it at the end of the constructor parameters list when declaring preferences for a block that adds more parameters ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `$data` can be used to populate data on your object since the constructor of `\Magento\Framework\DataObject` is this

```
public function __construct(array $data = [])
{
    $this->_data = $data;
}
```

or similar for `Magento\Framework\Api\AbstractSimpleObject`

```
/**
 * Initialize internal storage
 *
 * @param array $data
 */
public function __construct(array $data = [])
{
    $this->_data = $data;
}
```

which a lot of classes in Magento extend from.

A common use is in conjunction with a factory. For example in
`Magento\Sales\Model\Order\CustomerManagement` we have:

```
$this->addressFactory->create(['data' => $addressData]);
```

which essentially populates the `$data` array at creation.

Having to keep the `$data = []` at the end of the list of parameters is normal php behaviour since you are assigning a default value - the empty array.

Answer (score 17):

The `$data[]` can be used to hold values passed from `di.xml`'s arguments replacement mechanism, when `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct` intantiated.

In your case this could be populated by

```
<type name="\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct">
         <arguments>
             <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                 <item name="0" xsi:type="string">anystring</item>
                 <item name="1" xsi:type="string">xyz</item>
                <item name="2" xsi:type="string">abs</item>
            </argument>
         </arguments>
     </type>
```

You can even pass object and other formats to an array using above **di** mechanism. Further you can use those arguments while extending functionality. We can say, it is a kind of `va_list` in c.

This can be used when you don't want to modify the number of arguments in a constructor and want to inject other classes in your extended functionalities.

Comment: And how do we get the data from that $data array? Can you share an existing example or anything.