# Partial dependency injection

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

Is it possible to do partial dependency injection? For example, I have a class with a method called `findAttrValueByLabel`, and I want to be able to inject a `Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository`, but also pass two other parameters myself (namely `$attr_code` and `$label`). If it is possible, how do I do it? In fact, in general how do I call a method on a class with dependency injection? I know how to do it with the constructor only, because I just need to create it with object manager.

Comment: Maybe you could use the `$data` parameter in that case: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/118033/2380

Comment: Will that work when the values of `$attr_code` and `$label` are different every time the function is called? Also, in general how do i call a non constructor method which has dependency injected arguments? (ie what is the syntax)