# Dependency Injection with dynamic constructor values

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, dependency-injection

Is there a way to pass constructor arguments for dependencies when using the automatically generated factory classes?

I have an object structure that I would instantiate like this without the object manager:

```
new A(
  new AA(
    new AAA(
      'xyz'         <-- value determined at runtime
    )
  ),
  new AB(
    new ABA(),
    new ABB()
    [1,2,3]         <-- value determined at runtime
  ),
  new AC(
    ...
  )
);
```

Now I could replace this with a mix of factories and constructor injected arguments<sup>1</sup>, but I'm wondering if there is another way, something like this:

```
$aFactory->create(
  [
    AAA::class => ['param1' => 'xyz'],
    AB::class => ['param3' =>  [1,2,3]],
  ]
);
```

Alternatively it would also be useful if I could define a constructor argument to be fetched from a certain method with the `type` definition in `di.xml`.

Is there anything like this?

---

<sup>1) like this</sup>

```
$aFactory->create(
  [
    'aa' => $aaFactory->create(
      [
        'aaa' => $aaaFactor->create(
          [
            'param1' => 'xyz'
          ]
        )
      ]
    ),
    'ab' => $abFactory->create(
      [
        'param3' => [1,2,3]
      ]
    )
  ]
);
```

But what I'm trying to avoid is having to depend on all these factories

Comment: Isn't what you're describing the exact purpose of the `$data` argument ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/118040/2380

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism the data argument adds arguments to the class to be created, but not for its dependencies, or am I missing something?

Comment: It does not add arguments, it populates data from an array. But it definitely not deals with the existing dependencies from the constructor. My point was more "why not use the `$data` array instead of injecting class dependencies".

Comment: I updated my question with code how I would do it with factories and data arguments, is it that what you mean?

Comment: if you don't want that many direct dependencies, you can create one big factory that depends on the other factories. And you will depend on that big one only. Now I'm really curious about what you are building.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since what I tried is not possible, I ended up with a mix of preference definitions, generated factories and custom factories and decided case by case what makes sense.

1. I replaced the outermost instantiation with a factory. `AFactory` is the autogenerated factory for `A` (autogeneration of factories works for external libraries just as well as for classes of the module)

   ```
   $this->aFactory->create([
       ...
   ]);
   ```
2. For all constructor parameters of `A` without runtime configuration (ex. `AC`) I defined preferences in `di.xml` to pass the right objects.
3. For object structures that I want to be able to replace as a whole, I created custom factories, with an interface and defined them as preference. Ex. `AA`:

   ```
   interface AAInterrfaceFactory
   {
       /** @return AAInterface */
       public function create();
   }

   class AAFactory implements AAFactory
   {
       public function create()
       {
           return new AA(
               new AAA(
                 'xyz'         <-- value determined at runtime
               )
          );
       }
   }
   ```
4. For objects from the library that could not be replaced anyways (ex. `AB`), I stick with "new". If possible, parameters are injected into the class where the whole creation happens.

#### So in the end the instantiation can look like this:

```
return $this->aFactory->create(
    [
        'aa' => $this->aaFactory->create(),
        'ab' => new AB(
            $this->aba,
            $this->abb,
            [1, 2, 3]
        )
    ]
);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about what you're trying to achieve but I think you could do something like this:

```
$aFactory->create(['param1' => 'xyz', 'param3' => [1,2,3]]);
```

Then in the constructor of `$aFactory` you can do:

```
$this->_aa = $aaaFactory->create($data['param1']);
$this->_ab = $abFactory->create($data['param3']);
```

Comment: In theory, yes. But to make it more complicated, `A` is not part of the Magento module. So I need a way without changing these classes.

Comment: @fschmengler what about creating a new class that extends `A` so you can change the constructor ?

Comment: It's also final :D besides, I don't like that solution, then I'd rather use the factories. But I just realized that I probably don't need to change these classes for your suggestion, just create my own factories instead of the autogenerated ones.

Comment: @fschmengler "it's also final" damn yeah out of ideas here. My solution is definitely not the most elegant I agree but your problem doesn't sound that complex, refactoring the factories (see what I did here?) could definitely lead to a more elegant solution